# BradLarson/GPUImage：When I put test code in a new single application project as follows,it does not work

Tags: gpuimage

using default viewcontroller and mainstoryboard:
using pod install to setup the library.
This is a seggested Filtering live video test code，but it does not work on my iPhone6s.

[GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    enter code here
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

   GPUImageFilterGroup *group=[[GPUImageAmatorkaFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImageFilter *customFilter=(GPUImageFilter *)[group filterAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[group filterCount]);



    GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 375, 480)];

    [self.view addSubview:filteredVideoView];

    [videoCamera addTarget:customFilter];
    [customFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];

    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];

}

@end
```

Comment: As you already provided your code it is good to provide the error your receiving also. See how to ask questions here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no error.Even no warning.